# New theory for unifying general relativity and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

The media is currently reporting on a new idea in theoretical physics, developed by the group of professor Jonathan Oppenheim, to unify general relativity with quantum theory. The novel idea is not to quantize general relativity, which is assumed to be the most promising idea and as is central to string theory and loop theory, but instead to allow classic fluctuations in spacetime at a sufficiently small scale.

The following article gives an insight in how these fluctuations may lead to unification:
https://www.sciencenews.org/article/gravity-quantum-mechanics-physics-theory

The famous two-slit experiment apparently plays an important role. Due to the spacetime fluctuations, a particle such as an electron behaves like a wave, which experiences interference in the two-slit experiment and thus causes the well-known interference pattern on the screen.

If this is correct, then the new theory seems to solve one of the great questions in physics: why does a particle with momentum $p$ acquire wave-like behaviour with a wavelength prescribed by De Broglie's formula $p = h/\lambda$ ?

Can it really be so simple? What do the experts think?

Comment: quote from themselves :"When we started, maybe 99 percent of our colleagues thought we were crackpots and that’s now down to maybe 70 percent,” quips Oppenheim, of University College London." in your link, It is still non main stream physics , so not appropriate to be discussed in this site.

Comment: *..not to quantify general relativity..* you mean quantize?

Comment: @annav According to that argument then string theory and loop quantum gravity should also not be discussed on this site. Since they are often discussed here, this question should also be allowed.

Comment: @annav there exists no theory at this point that successfully combines QM with GR, so there is no such a thing as mainstream theory on this subject.

Comment: @flippiefanus loop quantum gravity and and string theory are published in mainstream peer reviewed papers, so are mainstream **research**. Is there a peer review for this?

Comment: @Andrei see answer above

Comment: @annav The paper on the theory in question was [published](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.13.041040) in Phys. Rev. X. I think that this level of scrutiny is enough for this site.

Comment: See also [APS Physics Viewpoint](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v16/203) piece for a popular account.

Comment: Also see the [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HHv3T4UHec&t=96) from Sabine.

Comment: @A.V.S. it is online only

Comment: @annav calling this non-mainstream physics is quite ridiculous. Oppenheimer is a very credible physicist and his works on many topics relating to quantum theory are reputable. I think it's quite clear you've not read these recent papers (though, as usual, the media's reports don't help).

Comment: @annav 'Is there peer review for this' - yes, look at essentially the last 3 years of work by Oppenheimer and colleagues https://inspirehep.net/authors/994824 many of which are published in top journals.

Comment: The question is off-topic, still: "Can it really be so simple? What do the experts think?" is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: @M.wind the papers that this article is based on are far from simple, but is based around the ideas of decoherence and back reaction. Essentially the equations end up being *stochastic*. But the authors do not claim this theory to be fundamental, and could still be an approximation for some deeper formalism we do not yet (or never will) understand

Comment: @TobiasFünke it could be re-worded as asking for clarification or further explanation. Anyway, the short answer is 'no, it's still not simple at all.' If I have time later I'll post an expanded answer

Comment: @Eletie Yes, but the vote to close is still reasonable. If OP wants to edit and expand the question and make it on-topic, they can do so; if the question gets closed in the meanwhile, they can vote to re-open.

Comment: 'Novel idea' - most of the crackpots on vixra 'merge QM and GR' by denying QM and inventing classical fairytales to explain QM. If you're going to do this, you've got to explain why every single QM experiment for the past century is wrong and explained by classical methods, otherwise this is crackpot level stuff, but if popular news articles are talking about it and it came from someone with a university background then it must be credible, like 'The Next Einstein' Garrett Lisi...

Comment: @Eletie Oppenheimer died in 1967. This is Oppenheim

Comment: @annav Sorry, that was autocorrections from my phone lol. (I've met Jonathan quite a few times).

Comment: @annav, here you can find the peer-reviewed paper: "A Postquantum Theory of Classical Gravity?" Phys. Rev. X 13, 041040 – Published 4 December 2023

Comment: @bolbteppa Oppenheim has a credible track record in QM research and Rovelli takes the idea enough to make a bet against it (albeit at 5000-to-1 odds) so I don't think it is fair to call this "crackpot level stuff" - at most it is unorthodox.

Comment: I support the voices *against* calling this 'crackpot' science, which it clearly isn't. (It's fringe, but that is OK.) However, the question is out of the scope of the site. You're either asking for opinions (which this format really doesn't do well) or for some form of peer review (about which, see here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/8563).

Comment: Voting to re-open. Asking "What do the experts think ?" is not opinion-based and has a straightforward answer - the "experts" are not dismissing the idea but are not yet convinced either.

Comment: @gandalf61  the theoretical proposal is  published at the proper place at phys.rev.X , online peer reviewed they say. Emilio is correct in stating that this site cannot peer review, see his link, It will only get opinions and spread misinformation on the subject, to reopen it, IMHO

Comment: @annav I disagree. "What do the experts think ?" is asking for facts, not opinions. The facts are clear.

Comment: @gandalf61  "What do the experts *think*  ?" is asking for facts" we are on different pages, for me thoughts are opinions, not facts.

Comment: @gandalf61 The question asks for opinions and additionally it can lead to open end discussions, as the question has no well-defined scope; it is really off-topic. (also, "expert" is not a well-defined term IMHO, to begin with)

Comment: Gaslighting well-established journals, like Phys. Rev., tends to put the spotlight more on the disparager than on them. The Phys. Rev. journals are all mainstream as is both the paper and its contents. To address the question posed, a Wheelerism may be appropriate: "Quantum gravity without quantum gravity". Yes, it can be that "simple" - except that the formulation of hybrid dynamics is a highly non-trivial matter, not simple at all. Hybridization is a field filled with No Go landmines and we're not guaranteed that all have been detonated. He may yet get fried before he gets to the other side.

Answer (score 4):

> Can it really be so simple ?

Almost certainly not. Otherwise everyone in the physics community would be  convinced already; eye-watering amounts of funding would become available; and multiple teams would be hard at work building experiments to demonstrate the theory so that they could win a Nobel prize. Scientists are evidence-led, but that does not make them closed-minded.

> What do the experts think ?

Carlo Rovelli hasn't paid out on his [5,000-to-1 bet](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-physicist-who-bets-that-gravity-cant-be-quantized-20230710/) yet. Oppenheim leads a team at UCL and has a credible track record in quantum physics, so his "postquantum theory" isn't entirely crackpot, but consensus seems to be that it is still a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

> The novel idea is not to quantize general relativity

Not true, because all *fundamental* fluctuations are of [quantum nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). Quantum Field Theory states that all fields undergo quantum fluctuations, and if gravity is a field, then sure it must fluctuate too. But to deeply understand these space-time fluctuations we must come up with a theory which best describes these micro changes of gravity.

Take for example, [Uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle),
$$ \sigma _{x}\sigma _{p}\geq {\frac {\hbar }{2}} \tag 1$$

which relates particle momentum and coordinate **fluctuations**, with a Planck constant. (By the way, notice $\hbar$ in (1) equation, this means that fluctuations are quantized, and so if space-time fluctuates at the fundamental level, then it also should be quantized.)
But this equation is just a precursor to the full-scale QM theory based upon wavefunction, probability densities and Schrodinger equations.

Similarly, if we just state (and find-out) that space-time really fluctuates, but will not come-up with a Physics framework which would explain deeply the roots and boundaries of this type of fluctuations,- our understanding of gravity will never be complete.

So the claim "*New theory for unifying general relativity and quantum mechanics*" is just ridiculous,- authors just lay-out some pre-cursor work to a **greater things** in gravity research.